# Why do apps built on Xcode 6 seem to be using iOS 8 system libraries on a iOS 8 device and those built on Xcode 5 don't?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I need to submit an update of an app ASAP and when I ran it on a iOS 8 device using the Xcode 6 GM, many bugs popped up. When I ran the same app on a iOS 8 device using Xcode 5, those bugs didn't occur.

E.g. `- [UIScreen bounds]` is orientation dependent on iOS 8. When the app -landscape only- was run using Xcode 6, this new behaviour could be noticed by many UI elements being mispositioned. The same did not happen when I ran the app using Xcode 5 on the same iOS 8 device.

Comment: the behaviour of - [UIScreen bounds] is changed in ios 8. Now in landscape it returns 568x1136 for iphone 5 for instance. And I suppose your situation happens because in xcode 5 you compile you code with ios 7. And may be that's why ios 8 device behaves in a such way.

Comment: Can you help me understand what you mean by "in xcode 5 you compile your code with iOS 7" please? The deployment target, which is nothing else than the minimum iOS supported, doesn't change between Xcode versions.

Comment: look in build settings base sdk is by default the latest one. For xcode 5 it is ios7. So your app is build using it. May be it makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help. If you want to use your last comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build settings base sdk is by default the latest one. For xcode 5 it is ios7. So your app is build using it.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal, and is how Apple have historically provided backwards compatibility.

When you build with xCode 5, you're compiling against the iOS 7 SDK (assuming that's what you specified in Build Settings->Base SDK). The iOS device takes account of this when you run the app and gives you backwards compatible behaviour (mostly...).

As an example, if you build a project on xCode 5, you'll always get a screen size that is 320x568 (on a 4" screen), regardless of the OS you run on or orientation.

However, when you build on xCode 6, an iOS 8 device in landscape will give you a screen size of 568x320, while an iOS 7 device will report 320x568.

If you are building a new app on xCode 6, you should also be aware of the requirements to provide Launch Images (as opposed to Launch Screens) for an app that targets iOS 7 or earlier. As per the docs:

> Applications targeting iOS 7.x or prior releases need to also supply
>   traditional launch PNGs via an asset catalog. Without launch PNGs for
>   iOS 7 and earlier, applications will run in the retina 3.5”
>   compatibility mode on retina 4” displays.